# How to download IMAP mails with MultiPart content using JavaMail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap, multipart

I cant find solution how to download multiple Emails with Multipart content with only one request to server (as batch fetching). The code i use:

```
FetchProfile lFp = new FetchProfile();
lFp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
lFp.add(FetchProfileItem.FLAGS);
lFp.add(FetchProfileItem.CONTENT_INFO);
pFolder.fetch(lMessages, lFp);
```

but when lMessages[i].getContent() is used, next request to server is performed. So for 50 next messages there are at least 50 more requests (+ nested Multiparts), it is not acceptable in my case.
How to speed it up?

Answer (score 1):

If you know that you always want to access all the content in the messages, you can use [IMAPFolder.FetchProfileItem.MESSAGE](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.FetchProfileItem.html#MESSAGE).

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler from what i have found, maybe i will check it in the future. Right now i use Justmaker's solution from this topic: [JavaMail IMAP over SSL quite slow - Bulk fetching multiple messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322836/javamail-imap-over-ssl-quite-slow-bulk-fetching-multiple-messages)

This method is incredible fast

EDIT:
@Bill Shannon i have tried Your solution. It is more sophisticated and also download nested MultiPart content including attachments